# mysql_start doesn't show prompt to write commands

Tags: mysql

I have installed xampp (for Windows xp) version 1.8.2

When I run `mysql_start` MySQL seems to start running (I can see this on xampp control panel and I can use phpMyAdmin to access databases data) but I can't send commands because no prompt is shown.

If I type something, nothing appears on screen, but if I stop MySQL from xampp control panel, prompt `c:\xampp>` is shown with the text I typed.

What happened?

Comment: MySQL has client-server architecture. You can't speak directly to the server, you need a client application.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario mysql_start.bat is the file who starts the console: I've already used it but now it doesn't work